# Android device not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, android-studio-2.1

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04, and Android Studio 2.1.2.

I have tried these [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) to try to run the app in a physical device, without any luck.

Am I missing something? It is the first time I try Ubuntu, so I'm kinda new to it. Also, I'm trying with a LG Stylus 3 device. (With debug option enabled).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does "adb devices" say when you have the device plugged-in? Also, do you have USB debugging enabled on your Android phone (and is the USB in a mode that allows for data transfer, not just charging)?

Comment: adb devices say: "List of devices attached" and no results below that. And yes, I have USB debugging enabled, and using the correct usb mode. (I have access to the phone's files in my PC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of things I tried, this was the solution.

I followed this [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461729/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device)

And what did the trick was to change in my phone the "USB PC connection" from Media device (MTP) to Send Images (PTP).

Answer (score 3):

I have two USB cords for my Moto X, and both can charge, but only one can transfer data. The one that can only charge does not allow my smart phone to show up in Ubuntu 16.04. It only dawned on me what the problem was when I realized that I was using the short cord that I keep with the phone in its case. After switching to the cord that can transfer data, all is well. So, check your cord (somehow, someway, but I do not know of any way to tell the difference between the two types of cords. A close comparison of both ends of both cords do not reveal any obvious differences).

Comment: It didn't solved all my issues but at least changing the cable made my device appear.

Comment: My god, I didn't even consider this possibility and was using a generic charger. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After running these two commands the phone recognized the USB connection and allowed me to transfer files as normal.. hope this helps someone..

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp*

sudo apt-get install mtp-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Htc E8 is:

Open Settings> About> Software Information> More.
Then tap “Build number” seven times to enable Developer options. ...
Go back to Settings menu and now you'll be able to see “Developer options” there.

Developer options> select usb configuration> PTP

Answer (score -2):

You can try to remove the temporary files from your Ubuntu PC.

**Reason:**

Many times this happens that we forget to unmount our device and this leaves some temporary files in our system which may result that our device is not recognized the next time.

You may refer this link for the same: [Delete Temporary Files in Ubuntu](https://websiteforstudents.com/automatically-delete-trash-temporary-files-ubuntu-17-10/)

This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: please specify if I had mistaken somewhere so that I can improve or else remove the answer.